# How to remove # from url in Angular4 / Expressjs routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, routes

I have created express routes which serves respective angular2 index.html files from dist folder, that is working fine, but the url are loading with # tags when they are loaded.

I tried changing the location strategy to PathLocationStrategy in app.module.ts but then the route renders the express's root index file.

I also tried by removing the "provide: LocationStrategy" from the providers option & only keeping the "provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: './' " option, but that also doesn't work.

Any guidance in this regards will be helpful.

**server.js**

```
app.use('/', express.static('client/dist'));
app.use('/iot', express.static('iot/dist'));
app.use('/mwc', express.static('mwc/dist'));
app.use('/canteen', express.static('canteen/dist'));
```

**IOT - app.module.ts**

```
  providers: [ 
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: './' },
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
    ModelService, 
    ListModelComponent
  ],
```

**IOT - index.html**

```
<base href="./">
```

**URLlooks like currently**

```
http://localhost:3020/iot/#./
```

**How it should look**

```
http://localhost:3020/iot
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
@NgModule({
imports: [routing, RouterModule.forRoot(routing,{ useHash: false})]
```

Comment: I solved it by just removing both the "provide" options & placing a '.' to my base reference in index.html file which I think I had not placed previously.